# Regex for findings names with title

Tags: regex

I am creating a web spider to retrieve information from a specific website. The names on the website are formatted as, "SMITH, JOHN ANTHONY" or, "SMITH JR, JOHN ANTHONY".

The regex I am using is, `[A-Z]+, [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+`. I would like to have the regex pick up the 'JR' as well if the name is formatted that way. Obligatory sentence saying how I am new to Regex and that this is my first post to Stack Overflow.

`[A-Z]+, [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+`

Answer (score 0):

You could use an optional group `(?: [A-Z]+)?` to match a space and 1+ times A-Z:

```
[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?, [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Mbo5tz/1)

You might use word boundaries `\b` prepended and appended to make sure the first and last match is not part of a larger word.

```
\b[A-Z]+(?: [A-Z]+)?, [A-Z]+ [A-Z]+\b
```